# How to construct a Class whose variables have almost same value for majority of the objects

Tags: java, oop

What is the best way to construct an Object which has only one variable being changed for multiple invocations.

```
public class Brand {

    final private Long id;
    final private String code;
    final private String version;
    final private String type;
    final private List<String> listThatChanges;
}
```

Most of the times I have to change the listThatChanges and put the object inside another Collection. Im thinking having a four argument constructor like below

```
   public Brand(id,code,version,type) {
        this.id = id,
        this.code = code;
        this.version = version;
        this.type = type;
    }
```

and a setter for listThatChanges, but this doesn't help me in any memory Optimization as I have to create a new Object anyways.Is there a better way to efficiently create a Class so that dont have reconstruct the same(except one attribute) Object multiple times

Comment: What classes best model the concepts you're trying to represent? Focus on modeling the problem space correctly and forget about optimization, at least for now. Correctness first. Tuning later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: [don't optimize unless you have a need to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Second:

If only one part changes, then that should in fact be the only thing that change, and you can reflect that by embracing composition and introducing a wrapper object.

```
class BrandAttributes{
  final Brand brand; // this object always stays the same
  final List<String> attributes; // this one changes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Brand {
    final private Long id;
    final private String code;
    final private String version;
    final private String type;
}

public class BrandWithList {
    final private Brand brand;
    final private List<String> listThatChanges;
}
```

Try to encapsulate what stays the same.

Answer (score -1):

The code can be restructured, but has not much room for memory optimization

Still if you want to

- Use long primitive, instead of  Long Wrapper

  final private long id;
- Initialize the ArrayList with size 0

  this.listThatChanges = new ArrayList(0)

Comment: As you create an instance of your class your are creating a new object in your heap memory, this not the same object. Depending on your needs or your implementation, you can create a `singleton instance` that is unique. But what if all your instances point to the same object? What if your want to create an `ArrayList` of your class.  It sounds like you need to you use the `Factory Pattern` to separate the creation of your object.

Comment: Gentlemen ! I do realize the mistake now. Edited Answer. Thanks! @JohnKugelman, @ HarryCoder